# Обновление данных в mysql c импортом CSV файла

Tags: mysql, utf-8, csv, update, импорт

```
здравствуйте,помогите пожалуйста решать вопрос при загрузке файла csv в 
mysql .
При формате UTF8 после загрузки не обновляется данные а добавляет новый id и 
данные.
Этой проблемы нет при другой формате,но в этом случае кириллица записывается 
не корректно,
прикрепляю скрины 
https://ibb.co/kekh2w
https://ibb.co/hSo22w
https://ibb.co/ib4aNw
https://ibb.co/cEJ22w
```

Comment: `LOAD DATA` **ВСЕГДА** добавляет новые записи.

Comment: Когда кодировка другая (ANSI),обновляет по id,только русские буквы записывается не корректно
https://ibb.co/gZ6Yub
https://ibb.co/c2VF7w
https://ibb.co/njJeZb
https://ibb.co/bEua7w

Comment: Программа делает запрошенную операцию как минимум в 2 этапа. Первый - импорт CSV во временную таблицу. Второй - INSERT в рабочую. И как он это делает - не видно. Посему рекомендую написать эти два запроса и выполнить именно их. И контроля за процессом больше будет.